# How can i make a specific row bold?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am working on generating a pdf and till now its going fine, but i want some specific rows to be bold. for example see picture : [grid template from jspdf-autotable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d96dW.png)
How can i make for example, row with id =1 and id=3 bold? Below my code.

```
function createPDF() {
            if(vm.activeCompanyYear){
                var url = "/coci/report/registry/"+vm.activeCompanyYear;

                DataApiService.callApi(url,null,"GET").then(function(reportData){

                    if(reportData){
                        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
                        var row = 45;
                        addPdfHeader(doc, row, "");
                        doc.printingHeaderRow = true;
                        var columns = [ "Description", vm.activeCompanyYear,vm.activeCompanyYear-1, vm.activeCompanyYear-2,vm.activeCompanyYear-3,vm.activeCompanyYear-4,"% t.o.v.'13" ];

                        var rows = [];

                        for(var j=0; j<reportData.length; j++){
                            var obj = reportData[j];

                            if (!obj.description ) {obj.description = '';}

                            if (!obj.year5 ) {obj.year5 = '';}

                            if (!obj.year4 ) {obj.year4 = '';}

                            if (!obj.year3 ) {obj.year3 = '';}

                            if (!obj.year2 ) {obj.year2 = '';}

                            if (!obj.year1 ) {obj.year1 = '';}

                            if (!obj.delta ) {obj.delta = '';}


                            /*TODO : Align data right in grid*/

                            var singleRow = [obj.description,obj.year5,obj.year4,obj.year3,obj.year2,obj.year1,obj.delta];
                            rows.push(singleRow);

                        }                       

                        doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
                            theme : 'grid',
                            styles: {
                                    halign: 'right',
                                     },
                            headerStyles: {
                                         fillColor: [33, 150, 243],
                                         halign:'center'
                            },
                            margin : {
                                top : 100
                                },
                            columnStyles:{
                                 0: {halign:'left'}
                            }

                        });


                        vm.isLoading = false;
                        blockUI.stop();
                        /* doc.save(); */
                        vm.reportData = doc.output('datauristring');

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
doc.autoTable({
  html: '#table',
  didParseCell: function(cell, data) {
    if (data.row.index === 0 || data.row.index === 2) {
      cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold';
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi friend, I tried it like the following and it worked : 

doc.autoTable(cols, data, {
  createdCell: function(cell, data) {
    if (data.row.index === 0 || data.row.index === 2) {
      cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold';
    }
  }
})

Comment: For me, data parameter was coming as undefined and had to use cell parameter itself as shown below:
`      didParseCell: function(cell, data) { 
        if (cell.row.index === 0) { 
          cell.cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold'; 
        }
      },`
Not sure why this was happening.

Comment: Hey @Sharath, it's because they change the function to receive only one parameter that includes both cell and data.  Instead function (cell, data) use function (hookData) and then inside use hookData.data and hookData.cell respectively

Answer (score 2):

I tried it like the following and it worked :

```
 doc.autoTable(cols, data, { createdCell: function(cell, data) { if (data.row.index === 0 || data.row.index === 2) { cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold'; } } })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I suggested edit queue is full for the top accepted comment I will add my own comment with the fix

```
  doc.autoTable({
    html: '#table',
    didDrawCell: function (hookData) {
      if (hookData.section === 'body') {
        if (hookData.row.index === 2) {
          for (const cell of Object.values(hookData.row.cells)) {
            cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold';
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById(m));
        var idm=document.getElementById(m);
               // console.log("res.rows",res.rows);
                var clength=res.columns.length;
                 var crow=res.rows.length;
        //console.log("columns.length:",clength);
        //console.log("rows.length:",crow);
                var fsize;
                if(clength>13)
                     {fsize=10;}
                else  if(clength>10) 
                     {fsize=10;}
                else  if(clength>7) 
                     {fsize=10;}
                else  if(clength<6) 
                     {fsize=10;}
                if(PdfType=='Flexible')
                     {fsize=7.5;}
                      

    
               //console.log("res.columns:", res.columns, "res.data:", res.data, res);
         doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {margin: {top: vy+25},pageBreak: 'auto',styles: {cellPadding: 1.5,fontSize:fsize , },fontStyle: 'bold',drawRow: function (row, data) {
                currentRow = row;
                        currentRow.height =30;
                       // console.log("row",row);
                       // console.log("data::::",data);
                       
                     
 if((currentRow.cells[0].text[0].includes('Total')) || (currentRow.cells[0].text[0].includes('Avg'))||(currentRow.cells[0].text[0].includes('count'))||(currentRow.cells[0].text[0].includes('Min'))||(currentRow.cells[0].text[0].includes('Max')))

  {
                     // console.log("cell length",res.columns.length);
                      
                      //console.log("cell",currentRow.cells[i].text);
   
                         for(var i=0;i<res.columns.length;i++)
                              {
                              
                                  currentRow.cells[i].styles.fontStyle = "bold";
                                  currentRow.cells[i].styles.font = "sans-serif" ; 
                                  currentRow.cells[i].styles.fillColor = [243,205,204];                 
                                  currentRow.cells[1].styles.columnWidth="wrap";
                                  currentRow.cells[1].styles.FontSize=30;
                                  
                                  }
                                 
                               
                                  
  }                    
        
                
    },columnStyles: {0: {columnWidth: columnwidthrgroup},},});
```

I just take all cell in that row thats easy