# How to achieve these goals with jsPDF-AutoTable plugin

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF-AutoTable and almost compleated my report, but I need few more changes if possible, I dont know if plugin can handle these three changes.

1.Make Day number in calendar **Bold** so they can be more readable (they are span tags in html).

2.Decrease the space between paragraphs.

3.If possible make text (paragraphs) with borders or distinguish somehow.

[see photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggCwq.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i make a specific row bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743672/how-can-i-make-a-specific-row-bold)

Comment: My goal is not to make entire row bold, i am trying to make bold only the Day Number inside a Cell, not entire row or column, but I didn't find out how to target first text in a Cell to make it bold untill now